# Non-trivial $\frac{1}{2}$-derivations Lie algebras

Tags: lie-algebras, poisson-geometry, derivations

I came across the following theorem:

> Let $\mathcal{L}$ be a Lie algebra without non-trivial
> $\frac{1}{2}$-derivations. Then every transposed Poisson
> structure defined on $\mathcal{L}$ is trivial.

If $\mathcal{L}$ is a Lie algebra without non-trivial, then left-multiplication by a scalar $\lambda$ won't be a $\frac{1}{2}$-derivation, $\lambda \left[x ; y\right] \neq  \frac{1}{2}\left[\lambda x ; y\right] + \frac{1}{2}\left[x ; \lambda y\right]$, but I don't know how to arrive at that every Poisson structure should be trivial and even if the last inequality could be considered. Any suggestions

Comment: See [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2311.00459.pdf), Remark $4$. It is explained before, how this arises.